# Mapinfo workspace won't open

Tags: mapinfo

When I try to open my workspace file, renamed 'FILE' here, it gives this error:

(FILE.wor:201) Found [)] while searching for [A string constant].
(FILE.wor:204) set is an invalid indentifier.
(FILE.wor:204) Unable to create map layer.
(FILE.wor:204) Unable to create map group layer.

I have tried opening the file in notepad to see if I could find a 201 or 204 but there are none, so it must be embedded somewhere in the file.
Who can tell me how to fix this?

Thanks!
Bertus

Answer (score 3):

201 and 204 refers to the line in the workspace.

So you'll have to open the workspace in a text editor and go to those lines to identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I did not find the exact problem, but replaced those lines with the similar ones from an older backup of the file. This seemed to work after a bit of tinkering.

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted answer. Doing so will increase reputation points for yourself, and for Peter. Thanks.